# Vue and Node.js cannot import file module 'module' from 'location'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, import, components

I'm trying to load a vue component into an HTML file but I have the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './../vue/modules/component-header' from 'D:\Dev\project\public\js'

There is my **index.html**:

```
...
<body>
    <section id="home-section">
        <component-header></component-header>
    </section>
</body>
...
```

**index.js** (loaded into the index.html)

```
import Header from './../vue/modules/component-header';

Vue.component('component-header', Header);

new Vue({
    el: '#home-section',
    render: h => h(Header)
});
```

And my **component-header.vue**:

```
<template>
    <header>Test</header>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "component-header"
    }
</script>
```

I'm also using **Browserify**:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let browserify = require("browserify");

browserify(["public/js/index.js"])
    .transform("babelify")
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("public/dist/index.js"));
```

And here's the folder structure (parent folder is 'project'):

[image: structure]

I've tried to modify the 'import' path inside the **index.js** but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you share the folder structure too?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with a screenshot of the structure.

Comment: just for the sake of trying. What happens if you move `component-header.vue` into the same folder as the `index.js` file and change the import line to `import Header from './component-header';`

Comment: I tried to do that, but still I've the exact same error: Error: Cannot find module './component-header' from 'D:\Dev\project\public\js'